# How to pack/publish a .NET Standard Library to a private VSTS Nuget feed?

Tags: .net, git, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to figure out how to pack/publish a .Net Standard 1.4 class library project to a VSTS private nuget feed.

- Code repo is GIT. Located in VSTS. (I acutally have a few GIT repo's under a single project in VSTS)
- Repo has 2x csprojs. 1x .Net Stanard 1.4 class library. Other one is an xunit .net core project.
- Need to create the nuget package.
- Need to then publish it to the private nuget feed as part of this VSTS project.
- For version numbers, right now I don't really care. Auto incremement based on some/any number (i'm used to using AppVeyor which has it's own remembered build number).

Has anyone done this before? Can someone show a screen shot of their build steps and/or hints/links to how to do this please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a VSTS build definition with below four tasks to pack and publish your .net standard library project to your VSTS feed:

#### .NET Core task

Command: `restore`

Project(s): path for your .net standard library project, such as

```
project/dotnetStandard/ dotnetStandard.csproj
```

#### .NET Core task

Command: `build`

Project(s): path for your .net standard library project

#### .NET Core task

Command: `pack`

Project(s): path for your .net standard library project

Arguments:

```
/p:PackageVersion=1.0.0 --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

Commands: `push`

Path to NuGet package(s) to publish: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg`

Target feed location: select **This account/collection**

Target feed: select the VSTS feed you want to publish

Comment: So there is -no way- to specify the nuget package _version_ at any time, via CLI?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Specify /p:PackageVersion argument. dotnet pack /p:PackageVersion=2.1.0

Comment: @Pure.Krome Hi, you can specify package version by `/p:PackageVersion` as starain said, and you can also find the option in the bottom of dotnet pack document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack. Sorry for the guide yesterday, and I updated it in my answer.

Comment: Yeah - I got the `/p:PackageVersion` working yesterday actually! I just haven't had time to post my results in here. but yeah :) awesome!